# Using Scapy to extract payload data from a PCAP

Tags: python, scapy

I would like to calculate the payload size of the packets from a PCAP file using Scapy below is where I found a function that does this and works out all the payload size stats e.g. median/min/max etc.

How can I use this function on my PCAP file and do I need to do anything to my PCAP file before I process it using this function.

Can this be written simpler?

```
def calc_IP_payload_size_features(packet_list, filter_con):
    global IP_len
    global IP_len_list
    global slice_length
    IP_len_list = []

    for i, (packet, dev_name) in enumerate(packet_list):
        try:
            IP_len.append(packet["IP"].len - packet["IP"].ihl)
        except IndexError:
            # IP_len.append(0)
            pass
        yield packet, dev_name

    # print("IP_len", IP_len)
    IP_len_list.append(IP_len)
    IP_len = []

    for i, (data) in enumerate(IP_len_list):
        if len(data) == 0:
            data.append(0)
        data = data[:min(slice_length, len(data)-1)]
        min_ip_len = min(data)  # minimum IP packet size
        max_ip_len = max(data)  # maximum IP packet size
        q1_ip_len = np.percentile(data, 25)  # first quartile of IP packet size
        median_ip_len = np.percentile(data, 50)  # median of IP packet size
        mean_ip_len = np.mean(data)  # mean of IP packet size
        q3_ip_len = np.percentile(data, 75)  # third quartile of IP packet size
        var_ip_len = np.var(data)  # variance of IP packet size
        iqr_ip_len = q3_ip_len - q1_ip_len  # IQR of IP packet size

        # print(i, "IP payload size features: ", min_ip_len, max_ip_len, q1_ip_len, median_ip_len, mean_ip_len, q3_ip_len, var_ip_len, iqr_ip_len)

        feature_list[i].append(min_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(max_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(q1_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(median_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(mean_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(q3_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(var_ip_len)
        feature_list[i].append(iqr_ip_len)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The last 3 lines are asking 3 questions. Can you reduce this to one question so that it can be answered?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for help with using this function with a pcap file. Where did this function come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can read pcap files with scapy like this:

```
pcap_contents = rdpcap("/path/to/foo.pcap")
```

source: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-pcap-files

This will return a `scapy.plist.PacketList`, which you can iterate over using standard Python techniques, for example a `for` loop:

```
for packet in pcap_contents:
    print(len(packet))
```

Your loop however seems to expect the `packet_list` to contain tuples of `(packet, dev_name)`:

```
for i, (packet, dev_name) in enumerate(packet_list):
```

My random sample pcap file certainly didn't produce this kind of data, so you probably need to match each packet with a `dev_name` first, to produce a list of `(packet, dev_name)` `tuple`s. This can be done using standard Python methods, e.g. with `for` loops, or, if you've got a list of `dev_names` where the indices match, you could `zip` the lists:

```
packets = [IP()/TCP(), IP()/UDP()]
dev_names = ['foo', 'bar']
packet_list = zip(packets, dev_names)
```

`filter_con` doesn't appear to be used, so I can't comment on that.